# Modelsim out of range error

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim

I am getting this error in ModelSim 10.1c:

> Fatal: (vsim-3421) Value 3079 is out of range 0 to 3078.
>
> Fatal error in Process wr_addr at C:/videoalgo/run_chkin/veu/median/median/board/sim/../../../window_gen/rtl/fifo.vhd line 159

I have the following types and signals defined. As you see, the declared index range is only 1029 down to 0:

```
type memory_type is array (natural range <> ) of std_logic_vector(29 downto 0);
signal MEMORY :   memory_type(1029 downto 0):=  (others => (others => '0'));
signal wr_port_address :std_logic_vector(10 downto 0)   :=  (others => '0');
signal wr_port_address_binary : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0):=(others => '0');
```

And the process where I'm getting the error is:

```
if rising_edge(Wr_Clk) then
    if A_rst = '1' then
        wr_port_address_binary <=  (others => '0');
    else
        if (Wr_Ena = '1') and (fifo_full = '0') then
            wr_port_address_binary <=  wr_port_address_binary + 1;
            -- the following is line 159
            MEMORY(to_integer(unsigned(wr_port_address)))   <=  Wr_Data;
        end if;
    end if;
end if;
```

Comment: I have formatted and improved your question a lot. Please check, if I have made something wrong.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiabe example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): reduce your code as much as possible so that the error is still present. And please post also the minimal testbench needed to trigger the error.

Comment: Hi Martin,  Formatting is alright.. It's part of project, so difficult to post testbench related to this error. If u could throw some light on where to look for resolving this, that would be helpful..

Comment: @kaps Martin's point is that in order to solve your problem, someone will have to do some work. They will need to add an entity and architecture and some kind of testbench. Instead of them doing that work, how about you doing that? I don't mean posting your whole project, I mean posting something small, which isolates the problem. Then, not only do you save the person helping you some time, there is a good chance that in the act of doing that you discover the problem yourself.

Comment: @kaps: You have not shown the relevant part of the code. The fatal error is related to an integer subtype with range 0 to 3078, which is incremented or used beyond the valid range. Find this integer, and you are closer to fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What process drivers the `wr_port_address`? You can't write to `MEMORY` using a number outside [0, 1029] range.

Taking the filename 'fifo.vhd' as a hint, you should reset the `wr_port_address` signal whenever it reaches the top of your memory. I'll assume that `wr_port_address_binary` is the same thing as `wr_port_address` apart from some weird name and/or type change (if it isn't you should really rename them).

```
if rising_edge(Wr_Clk) then
    if A_rst = '1' then
        wr_port_address <=  (others => '0');
    else
        if (Wr_Ena = '1') and (fifo_full = '0') then
            if wr_port_address < 1029 then
                wr_port_address <=  wr_port_address + 1;
            else
                wr_port_address <=  (others => '0');
            end if;
            -- the following is line 159
            MEMORY(to_integer(unsigned(wr_port_address)))   <=  Wr_Data;
        end if;
    end if;
end if;
```